# How to create variables from dictionary keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, variables

I have a dictionary that contains tkinter labels, but below I'm only including the first part of the dictionary

When I use variables, in the example below I get no errors.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

dic = {'response1':Label(root, bg='white')}

lbl = dic['response1']
lbl.config(text='Hey')
lbl.pack()

mainloop()
```

But when I do it without variables, like this

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

dic = {'response1':Label(root, bg='white')}

dic['response1'].config(text='Hey').pack()

mainloop()
```

I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'
```

and since that, I need to declare a variable for each label in the dictionary so that I can avoid this error. So I'm asking how to declare a variable for each item in dictionary, where the key is the variable name. So `response1 = Label(root, bg='white')` and so on for each item in the dictionary.

Comment: Why not just leave them as dictionary values?

Comment: @wim Because I need them as a variable type, the actual dict contains of tkinter buttons that I need to be able to do operations on. And if I just do dict['key'] I can not perform operations on them

Comment: What sort of operation can you do on a local variable that you can't do on a dictionary value?

Comment: @wim I have them as tkinter buttons so I need to be able to operations like `.config(text='Some text')` and `var1.pack()`. Otherwise, if I do `dict['var1'].pack()`, I get this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'`

Comment: Perhaps you can post the [mcve] which demonstrates such an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @IsaacK0 please supply the code you tried to do that with. I'm assuming there's some different error in your code. There should be no difference between a dictionary reference and regular one.

Comment: @OsmosisJonesLoL I will update my question

Comment: @IsaacK0 just looked up a little of tkinter to know what you are talking about
pack is a method on tkinter widgets, even if you did `var1.pack()` I'd be skeptical of it working correctly.

The assumption if you are making buttons they would look like
`button = Button(frame, text=var1)`
or
`button = Button(frame, text=dict['var1'])`

and then you can call `button.pack()`

Comment: @OsmosisJonesLoL Now it's updated, I tried to show a bit about what you looked up above

Comment: @wim The question is updated now

Comment: I've modified my answer to reflect your updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use variables, your error actually comes from you trying to use the results of .config, to .pack.

Try the following:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

dic = {'response1':Label(root, bg='white')}

dic['response1'].config(text='Hey')
dic['response1'].pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: [Read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals).

Comment: added a small disclaimer

Comment: answered the root cause of the problem, rather than the question initially addressed.

Comment: @OsmosisJonesLoL I thought I had tried that before, but clearly I hadn't, so thanks you, now I know how to do